# Spring Websocket setMaxSessionIdleTimeout not work in Openshift Tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, openshift, spring-websocket

I create a websocket app with Spring Websocket, when client connects to server, after about 1 minute idle, the server auto-closes the connection. I try to configure:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {WinkrSocketService.class})
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(webSocketHandler(), "/ws/winkr").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
        ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
        container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(8192);
        container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(8192);
        container.setMaxSessionIdleTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5));
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler() {
        return new PerConnectionWebSocketHandler(WinkrSocketHandler.class);
    }
}
```

Now every 5 minutes of idle, the server will auto-close the connection. It runs OK on local with Tomcat 7, but when deploy on Openshift, it does not work (still auto-close after 1 minute). I debugged and it really ran **setMaxSessionIdleTimeout()** on Openshift but does not effect!